# Why ploting data in ILNumerics produce the result that is not symmetry? (2D Plot)

Tags: matlab, model, plot, 2d, ilnumerics

I have ILNumerics code like this:

```
        var scene = new ILScene();

        ILColormap cm = new ILColormap(Colormaps.Hot);
        ILArray<float> data = cm.Data;

        data[":;0"] = ILMath.pow(data[":;0"], 3.0f);
        cm.Data = data;

        ILArray<float> contoh = ILMath.zeros<float>(15, 15);
        contoh[7, 14] = 1;

        scene.Add(
            new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false){
                new ILSurface(contoh){
                    Wireframe = { Color = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.LightGray)},
                    Colormap = new ILColormap(data),
                    Children = { new ILColorbar()}
                }

            }
        );

        ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
```

Roughly speak, I want to plot 2D model. In that matrix "contoh", I have one value that different with other neighbors. I want to plot that matrix become something like this figure:

[image: Figure 1]

But, there is that I got:
[image: Figure 2]

If we see the white area, it is not symmetry. Why this is happen? When I slightly rotate the model, we can see more clearly that even I have data in [14,7] position, the white area stretching until [13,6] but not to [13,8].

[image]

And for the last. Can anyone teach me how to make code that will generate a figure as like as Figure 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both plots are different because they are of different type. The matlab one is an imagesc, the ILNumerics one is a surface. Imagesc plots will be available for ILNumerics with the next release.

Comment: can't wait the next release.. :)
previously, I try to solve with drawing many triangle. but I get trouble with coloring scale..